# Using comparison on tableau connecting to prestodb, unicode letter does not work

Tags: unicode, tableau-api, presto

I am using Tableau,connecting to PrestoDB using Teradata Presto ODBC driver, to do filtering using calculated field to do comparison:

English: **rawsql_bool("product like 'Fresh'")**

[image: result for English]

Thai(unicode): **rawsql_bool("product like 'ไก่'")**

[image: result for Unicode]

Result for English is fine, but it turns out that result is not correct for Thai language since all of result show 'false' which it should not be.

I tried to run extracted raw SQL command, that I got from Tableau, directly in PrestoDb CLI and it works correctly. Am not sure if it because of some problem about ODBC driver or not? Is there anyone who got same problem like me?

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: @DainSundstrom Teradata Presto ODBC Driver. Thanks for asking. I've updated the question.